# Incorrect apostrophe usage on 'Thanks for submitting an edit' message

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Use of an apostrophe in the message below is incorrect.

"it's" is a contraction of "it is":

"It is only visible to you until `it is` been approved by trusted community members" reads poorly.
That sentence could also do with a full stop.

Correct alternatives:

- It is only visible to you until `its` been approved by trusted community members`.`
- `It's` only visible to you until it has been approved by trusted community members`.`

[image: Incorrect apostrophe usage]

Comment: "it has", informal usage.  Maybe not down-under.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying.  Wow, yeah, definitely not down under!  Yikes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_English_contractions

Comment: See [Is it proper to use “it's” as an abbreviation for “it has”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/395254/363732) on our very own network!

Comment: How is “its” correct here? _It is only visible to you until its **what?** been approved_

Comment: Interesting.  It would appear that the acceptance of this contraction is mainly centered around American English.  It is certainly not commonly seen in English in Australia.  With SO being international in nature, I'd suggest this bug still stands as a potential for improvement still.  Be welcoming through grammar, haha!

Comment: Regardless of regional variations on "it's," I don't think there is any version of English where "its" is correct there so your first alternative is definitely wrong.

Comment: @QACollective As a fellow down-under-er, it definitely is common here

Answer (score 16):

The message is correct as written.

*It's* is a contraction for either "it is" or "it has". In this case, "it's" is a contraction for "it has".

When fully expanded, the sentence reads:

> Thanks for submitting an edit. It is only visible to you until [such time as] it has been approved by trusted community members.

The first of your proposed "correct alternatives" is incorrect. "Its" is a possessive form of the pronoun "it", meaning "belonging to". The way you've used it in the first alternative is grammatically incorrect. There is no ownership here.

The second of your proposed alternatives is grammatically fine, but I don't see any advantage to this rephrasing. There is perhaps an argument to be made for altogether eschewing contractions, but in that case, you'd need to replace the initial "It's" with "It is". And contractions are often preferred in informal writing; the long-form is perceived as stilted and unfriendly.